# Angular how to share the same setting of json configuration file for different environment

Tags: javascript, angular, configuration-files

I have an Angular 9+ application that uses `APP_INITILIZER` to load the external json configuration file so that we can modify the file without rebuilding the app.

We have a few such configuration files for different environments like `dev`, `qa`, `staging`, etc. And in `angular.json` file, we specify which file to use in `assets` section.

We have some settings that are not related to environment. For example, the settings for colour

```
...
,
{
   "title":"red",
   "header":"blue"
},
...
```

The issue is each time we add new settings like above, we need to duplicate it in every config file. I wonder if there's a way to only add the common settings once, and reuse them in all other config files?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I usually take is to have a common environment file like environment.common.ts but the file looks slightly different

```
export const commonEnv = {
  title: 'red',
  header: 'blue'
};
```

I then just merge the settings with the normal environment file using Object.assign.

```
import { commonEnv } from "./../environment.common";
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

const mergedSettings = Object.assign(commonEnv, environment);
```

You can now use mergedSettings to get to all the settings.